# What are the available options when developing a decoupled, high scalable web application with server pushed events?

Tags: websocket, apache-camel, activemq-classic, stomp, sockjs

I would like to see if someone can clarify me some concepts I still don´t get about integration of web applications. Up until now, I´ve been working with CometD and Activemq in a project that´s been there for several years but, for what I´ve seen, there are other options out there much more simpler and supported by the community but I still don´t get the whole picture of options available.

So, for what I understand, at the moment, the most common way of getting server pushed events to a client is using websockets. The implementation is server specific and the most used one seems to be the Jetty one. But, because it requires a websocket compatible browser, there are some frameworks that are able to provide websockets and fall to reverse ajax techniques in case this is not an option, like SockJS, that has an implementation for client and for server side. Based on this, as of spring 4 there are templates that allow you to use SockJS behind the scenes and just provide the client implementation of the code using SockJS and letting the programmer to handle the server side in a more easy way.

Apart from this, brokers can understand the websocket protocol so a broker can receive a message from a web browser and then send a message back directly. There is also the STOMP protocol that brokers also implement that allows the system to send/receive messages through websocket to/from the web browser. 
One question I have about this is, is STOMP the protocol always used by the broker to send or receive a message to or from a web browser? Or is just one alternative? What is the difference if it´s the later?

Yet another option I´ve seen is using a framework like camel. In this case, the web browser would talk to the websocket component of camel and from there it could be routed directly to the broker using jms. The benefit I see on this is the possibility of introducing processors as part of the route from the browser to the broker, allowing further security processing and reducing the traffic the broker would have to handle in case of not valid/unauthorized messages. Camel would even be able to listen to messages using the STOMP component what would be yet another routing option.

So, to this point, I don´t know if my understanding is correct or if I miss or misunderstand something. If everything is right, it seems that using a framework like SockJS is the best option available at the moment. The use of Spring 4 to simplify things is an option but not really necessary. If the project requires the integration of different systems using a jms broker, the implementation then falls to use SockJS to send messages to the server side and then just route the messages to the correct system. But at this point, there are the options mentioned before like using camel to route the messages or directly send messages to the broker. What would be the best option, or what would be the differences? If I add STOMP to the problem, what does this protocol give me that I can´t handle just with websockets or camel?

I hope I made myself clear. I think this topic includes several technologies and frameworks and it´s quite difficult to express all my concerns without extending the post to much.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, if you want messaging semantics, you should use a messaging protocol such as STOMP. WebSockets sure can handle communication to browsers just fine, but that's just "any custom communication".

The system design **may** be cleaner if you design around the convention of topics and messaging. The server backend processes can easily push data to a topic that is propagated to all clients, ideally with no further customization.

Aside from STOMP, there is a similar protocol, MQTT which also can run over websockets. A chat demo is provided by ActiveMQ distribution. MQTT is very hot in the Machine2Machine world "internet of things", but I have used it with success in web-deployments too. MQTT should, at least in theory, run pretty good, with low overhead in phone apps, should you ever consider writing one side by side with your website. Then it can be good to use a single setup to communicate "push" data with your clients. Otherwise, your app may have used MQTT, your browser app would have used plain websocket, your backend would have needed another way to pass async events to clients (via some Camel router or similar) and so forth.

Comment: So for what I understand then, my assumptions about SockJS and Spring were right but not the other part about websocket and STOMP. To use websockets directly with a broker you need to specify the protocol (STOMP or MQTT), plain websockets is not an option. So, is there any benefit in using this instead of using something like camel to route the messages from a websocket channel to the broker using JMS? Couldn't the broker be overloaded if it's getting all these messages without any filtering? What about security? How do you secure a message that goes directly to the broker? Thanks.